# Car splutters and rpm won' increase when gas pedal is depressed intermitently

Tags: honda

I have a Honda civic 1.6 auto I have an intermittent fault sometimes from a stopped position, if you depress the throttle pedal it makes a (put put ) sound and the rpm won't increase then after a few seconds it will go as normal.
I have changed the fuel pump, fuel filter, spark plugs, MAP sensor, plug leads, coil rotor arm. and l still have the same problem.The ecu shows no faults found. Can anybody help me it would be much appreciated.

---

Hi Fred Yes l have engine check No Faults found from the ecu. Is 1998. has 155000 kilometres

---

Hi Ben the map sensor is new, I fitted a new Bosch feul pump had  it pressure tested while driving the car Reading 3.5 Bar. Engine vacuum ok no leaks.

Comment: Do you have a check engine light? Read for any codes? If so, what are they? What year is your Civic? How many miles?

Comment: How's fuel pressure? How's Engine Vacuum? What's the MAP sensor output read in volts?

Answer (score 1):

Start from basic principles (before you spend any more money on parts that aren't fixing the problem).

Check the static timing is correct.  Then perform a compression test.  If both of these things check out, check that the ignition timing is correct and that the ignition leads are on in the right order (you'd be surprised!).  Check that you have a nice strong spark.  Check that your fuel pressure at the fuel rail is good and check that you have appropriate readings from your throttle position sensor.

I've seen this kind of thing many many times and it almost always comes down to something very simple (like timing a tooth out or two ignition leads crossed over).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steve the plug lead are correct as this is an  intermitant fault normally when driving the cars run perfectly. It is only sometimes when  you start to drive from a stopped position.

Comment: In that case, I'd advise looking for vacuum leaks and breaks in the wiring harness.

Comment: Steve. Checked vacuum no leaks, but what l will say  is when the car splutters and rpm won,t increase, if you take out of drive (D4) and put the car in Netural the rpm goes up straight away. So can you shed any light on this.